# How to fetch nested document from firebase using React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This is the view of my database:

[image: 1]

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { db } from "../firebase";
import { collection, Firestore, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";

function Document() {
  const handleFetchData = async () => {

//What should I Write to get the documents from Kids collection
};

}

return (
  <div>
    <button onClick={handleFetchData}> Fetch Data </button>
  </div>
);

export default Document;
```

I want to get the innermost document (document of Kids collection) by just clicking on the button

Answer (score 1):

Try once with following code:

```
const ref = db.collection('Price List').doc('Dry Clean').collection('Kids');
const doc = await ref.get();
```

Comment: It is showing error " db.collection is not a function"

Comment: Then there must be error in initializing your db

Comment: Actually, This method was used used in firebase 8

Answer (score 0):

```
var docRef = doc(
          db,
          'Price List',
          'Dry Clean',
          'Kids',
          'Kids Shirt'
        );
    
        const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
    
        if (docSnap.exists()) {
          console.log('Document data:', docSnap.data());
        } else {
          // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
          console.log('No such document!');
        }
```

Actually the correct solution is this after firebase 9